# CycleOps Thru Axle Kit Help

Tags: trainer, through-axle

I just got the CycleOps thru axle kit and installed the thru axle on my Litespeed. The bolt action clamp that comes with the kit barely clamps around the axle cap on the thru axle though. Is this really how it's designed to work, and is it really enough to hold my bike in the trainer?

Here's a video showing this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsC0U.jpg

Comment: How old is your trainer?

Comment: It's from 2006, but the bolt action clamp that's on my trainer currently won't clamp on to the thru axle cap any better than the bolt action clamp that came in the kit and that's shown in the video.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't trust that to hold the bike.  Contact CycleOps and make sure you got the right size for your axle.   Or consider spinning up something on a lathe.  You might be able to finangle some old sockets that fit and hold better.

Comment: The odd thing is that the clamp and thru axle came together as part of the same kit, in the same packaging, and are supposed to work together. Even though it doesn't look like it will work (and looks like a horrible design), I can't imagine any other bike config that would allow it to work different. Anyway, I'll give them a call tomorrow.

Comment: @BenW How did that go?  Even if you have to post an answer to your own question, get an answer going so we can clear this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to use the trainer very much, but it appears to work. Everything seemed to hold fine.